# fitdist for truncated normal

Tags: r

The truncated normal is given by:

```
dtnorm<- function(x, mean, sd, a, b) {
dnorm(x, mean, sd)/(pnorm(b, mean, sd)-pnorm(a, mean, sd))
}
ptnorm <- function(x, mean, sd, a, b) {
(pnorm(x,mean,sd) - pnorm(a,mean,sd)) / 
  (pnorm(b,mean,sd) - pnorm(a,mean,sd))
}
```

The fit is given by:

```
fitdist( data, tnorm, method="mle",
                    start=list(mean=mapply("[[", results[1], 1),
                               sd=mapply("[[", results[1], 2)),
                    fix.arg=list(a=minLoose,b=maxLoose))
```

Where results[i] is a matrix with the mle results of fitdist using normal instead of tnormal.

I get the following results for tnorm:

```
mean=-0.00844725266454969, sd=0.012540928272073
```

whereas with norm:

```
mean=0.00748402597402597, sd=0.00614293813955003
```

The data is all larger than 0 and smaller than 0.04 so the mle obtained for tnorm does not seem right.... Any advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that your data is all above normal (er, rather above 0) has little bearing on whether the "mean" of best fit to a truncated distribution does or doesn't exceed 0. You are fitting a right tail of a Normal distribution to your data. The estimated location parameter for the truncated is not really a mean, but rather where the mean would be in an uncensored dataset with a right tail of the same density "shape" as your data. (This is really a stats question rather than an R question.)

You can find the formula to calculate the expected value of a doubly truncated Normal at the moments section of the Wikipedia article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution It is readily translatable into calls to `pnorm` and `qnorm`.

A further thought: Check out the facilities for working with truncated distributions in packages: 'gamlss' and 'gamlss.tr'.

Comment: I agree. But if I want to know the mean value of the tnorm distribution in the truncated range then I could compare it with the mean value of the norm... right?

Comment: The location parameter of a truncated normal is not the same as its mean. If you want the sample mean you just use mean(data). If you want the theoretic mean of a distribution with particular estimated parameters, then you should calculate x*ptnorm() across limits of the acceptable domain. Since you really haven't defined the problem completely, not much more can be said.

Comment: OK, Thanks, I got it. But can I only compute the moments of the tnorm within the acceptable domain using the method of moments? I'd like to compute them using mle as well to get the uncertainty, not only of the moments of the tnorm but also of the tnorm within the acceptable domain.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment, but perhaps the addition to my answer is responsive to it? You do have estimates for mu, sigma , and presumably a and b have been pre-specified.

Comment: So I run first the fitdist for norm to get the mle estimates of the Normal to my data and then feed these parameters to the mle fit to the truncated normal. As a resuly I got the mle estimates of the mean and sd of the tnorm which fits best my data on the acceptable domain. Next question is besides the method of moments (which you suggest) I'd like to also use again mle to obtain the estimates of the mean and sd of the tnorm now only on the acceptable domain as the mle also gives me uncertainty estimates.

Comment: If I understand your last question, I see no point in "run{ning} first the fitdist for norm". {Edit} If you have minLoose and maxLoose you should only be using fitdistr with ptnorm and dtnorm using those parameters. Using with dnorm and pnorm would be meaningless.

Comment: I saw your link. Thanks. But if I cannot find a way of comupting the mle estimates I'll try to get them by bootstrapping the tnorm and then estimating the moments by the method of moments to get an interval. Thanks!

Comment: I just use the first run the fitdist for norm because fitdist for tnorm needs starting estimates, and so this way it is more automatic. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use portions of this script that estimates the parameters

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))


dtnorm<- function(x, mean, sd, a, b) {
dnorm(x, mean, sd)/(pnorm(b, mean, sd)-pnorm(a, mean, sd))
}


simuls=5
simul_mat=matrix(nrow=simuls,ncol=6)
for(simul in 1:simuls) {
acm=rnorm(1)
acsd=runif(1)*2+0.5
limits=sort(acm+rnorm(2))

all=limits[1]
aul=limits[2]



x=rnorm(10000)*acsd+acm
x=subset(x,x>all & x<aul)




    norm_parms<-function(parms){
    mp=parms[1]
    sdp=parms[2]^2
    ll=median(x)-parms[3]^2
    ul=median(x)+parms[4]^2

    xs=subset(x,x>ll & x<ul)
    ds=dtnorm(xs,mp,sdp,ll,ul)

    if(length(x)>5){
    do=rep(dnorm(-6),length(x)-length(xs))
    ds=c(ds,do)
    }
    if(length(x)<=5){
    ds=rep(dnorm(-9),length(x))
    }


    mll=-sum(log(ds))
    return(mll)
    }



bestv=Inf
methodss=c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN")
for(method in methodss){
try(bestc<-optim(par=c(0,1,1,1),norm_parms,method=method))
if(bestc$value<bestv) {best=bestc;bestv=bestc$value}
}



parms=best$par
mp=parms[1]
sdp=parms[2]^2
ll=median(x)-parms[3]^2
ul=median(x)+parms[4]^2
print(c(acm,acsd,all,aul))
print(c(mp,sdp,ll,ul))
print(best$value)
acparms=c(acm,acsd,sqrt(median(x)-all),sqrt(aul-median(x)))
acv=norm_parms(acparms) 
cnames=c("Actual a","Estimated a","Actual b","Estimated b","Actual optim","Best optim`")
simul_mat[simul,]=c(all,ll,aul,ul,best$value,acv)

cnames=c("Actual a","Estimated a","Actual b","Estimated b","Actual optim","Best optim`")
colnames(simul_mat)=cnames
print(simul_mat)

}
```